# Google Assistant to IFTTT to update cell in Google Sheet. onEdit:yes, value:no

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A little confused.  I have this working in one sheet, but a different sheet is not.  Voice command through Google Assistant triggers IFTTT to send values to a certain cell in my spreadsheet.  With onEdit, the cell change triggers the function, correctly identifies the page, row, col of the edit, but no value.  Even pulling the row or column or sheet values show nothing in that cell.  Can see it on the screen.  It triggered the event, but no value as if the event is trigger prior to the value being set.

Comment: Question about code that isn't working should include a [mcve].

Comment: I see posts in the past where they said that IFTTT would not trigger onEdit at all.  It used to be only through user input.  The code is almost nothing.  Just taking the onEdit(e) > range=e.getRange(); value=range.getValue()  Logger shows nothing.  The code is exactly the same as a second sheet where it works.  I'm curious to know if this is even supposed to work and it is a fluke in the first sheet. Or, is it really not supposed to work because onEdit() is only for user input on the screen.